# Context click (right click) not working visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, selenium

I have made a number of test using selenium. I created my solution in visual studio 2015 and all of the tests run fine, however when I run my tests in visual studio 2017 all of my tests work apart from when I need to right click.

I'm not sure why this is happening only in visual studio 2017

I get a runtime error saying that the element is null however in the line before I try and right click I can left click on the element so I know the element is not null.

My code is as follows

```
   var webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(session, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        Actions action = new Actions(session);

        CommonMethods.switchWindows(session);
        CommonMethods.keyCheck(session);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(session.FindElementByName($"{fileName} - PowerPoint"))).Click();                
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(session.FindElementByName("Create"))).Click();
        webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(session.FindElementByName("View Links"))).Click();
        CommonMethods.IsElementDisplayed(session, new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber(), new StackTrace(true).GetFrame(0).GetMethod(), "CreateErrorIcon", "Error appeard when selecting the View Links button");
        webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(session.FindElementByName("Create"))).Click();
        var e =webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(session.FindElementByName(SlideNumber)));
        e.Click();              
        action.ContextClick(e).Perform();
        webDriverWait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementTo‌​BeClickable(session.FindElementByName(element))).Click();
        keyCheck(session);
```

Comment: Can you post the full exception?

Answer (score -1):

I figured out the issue. For some reason the latest Version of WinAppDriver(May 2017) doesn't context click. Download the March 2017 version and it solves the problem

Comment: It did for me. Have to got the same issue I was having?